# iPad live streaming not working

Tags: iphone, ipad, live-streaming

I am working on a universal app to which runs some live video streams.I prefer using webview as MPMoviePlayerController has always given me headahes.But video doesnt play on iPad (Both simulator and device)but it does work on iPhone.However if i load it using safari it loads perfectly.Any suggestions please?

Here is what i am doing

```
movieURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"my-stream-URL"];

NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:movieURL];
[webView_ loadRequest:req];
```

Comment: just made a URL request and loaded via UIWebview

Comment: post code. Nobody here is psychic

Comment: nice one coneybeare.anyways thanks for suggestions.This helps us learn more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is ofcourse use MPMoviePlayerController.I however was reluctant to use it as it wasnt allowing me the orientation with tabs(As all tabs must be orienting).So I used another view controller using as a basecontroller added it on tab and then pushed a ModelViewController over it and acheived complete orientation